# How to share objects in different client call to WCF?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I think when client do new wcfclient(), the WCF will create new thread to handle all the call from that connection? (I hope I am right).
So if there is different client make calls to WCF (say computer A & computer B), then the WCF should handle each client in different thread.  So if I want to share a object between those thread, how can I do it?

Use static object?

Is different client calls the WCF will treat it as different process? or is different thread?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), if truly only one instance should be shared across all requests. As I'm sure someone will be quick to point out - using this pattern is generally not a good idea. You will run into trouble with locking and scalability.

Better, though, would be to persist the object in some serial format. Either to a file or a database if that's possible. You can then re-materialize the object on subsequent requests.

Comment: Yes, but writting into a file or database it takes more process time(serialize/deserialze etc).  But  I think different clients's call will create different instance? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, I just checked there is instanceContext to do such setting. But what if I do PerSession? How can i share memory object?